# In Ant script, how to merge two or more xml files content into one xml file?

Tags: xml, xpath, ant

I am new to ant script. I am looking for how to merge two or more xml file into single xml file in ant script. Is it possible to achieve this via ant.
In my project n number of xml file will be generated dynamically in a folder eg: server1.xml, manager.xml, server2.xml, server3.xml. I need to merge all the xml files having server in their filename alone (server1.xml, server2.xml, server3.xml) into a single xml eg: server.xml.and need to deploy it in jboss.
I have found that copying content from one xml file to another as shown below.

```
target name="servlet"> <xmltask            
 source="src/web.xml" 
 dest="target/web.xml"> <!-- 
 nothing to do here yet -->    
  <\xmltask> </target>.
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to the error "Cannot use multiple buffer nodes as an input source" returned by the solution proposed by Daniele.
I made mine:

```
<for param="file">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="directory" includes="server-*.xml" />
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <local name="name"/>
        <basename file="@{file}" property="name" />
        <echo message="${name}"/>

        <xmltask source="@{file}" clearbuffers="c"> 
            <copy path="/rootTag/*" buffer="c" append="true" />
        </xmltask>

        <xmltask sourcebuffer="all" destbuffer="all"> 
            <paste path="/rootTag" buffer="c"/>
        </xmltask>
    </sequential>
</for>

<xmltask sourcebuffer="all" dest="server.xml" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `<xmltask>` (http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/), and let's say you have `src1`, `src2` and `dest` as files, you can first copy from `src1` into `src2` using the insert or paste from buffer, and then from `src2` to `dest` in the same way.

Please have a look at the insert of xmltask: http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/#usage.insert

I haven't tested it, but the below should do what you want:

```
<target name="mergeServerFiles">
 <xmltask clearBuffers="b"> 
  <fileset dir="${myDir}"> 
    <include name="server*.xml"/>           
  </fileset> 
  <copy path="//sectionYouWantToCopy" buffer="b" append="true"/>
 </xmltask>
 <xmltask sourcebuffer="b" dest="server.xml" />
 ....
 </target>
```

Comment: In my project n number of xml file will be generated dynamically in a folder eg: server1.xml, manager.xml, server2.xml, server3.xml. I need to merge all the xml files having server in their filename alone (server1.xml, server2.xml, server3.xml) into a single xml eg: server.xml.and need to deploy it in jboss. I am trying to achieve thid via ant script.

Comment: The solution doesn't work.
The error "Cannot use multiple buffer nodes as an input source" is returned.